# Create folders with file name and rename part of it

Tags: python, file, replace, python-os

i have some pdfs files that i need to create folders with part of your name and move the pdfs to the folders.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
padrao = '_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001.pdf'
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    dst = cwd + "\\" + file.replace(str(padrao), '').replace('P', '')
    os.mkdir(dst)
    shutil.move(file, dst)
```

ex: I have the file P*9883231*_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S000**01**.pdf,  P*9883231*_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S000**02**.pdf and
P1235567_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001.pdf.

In this example I need the script to create two folders: 9883231 and 1234567.  (the part in italics must be the name of the folder)

notice that in my code I remove the unwanted parts to create the folder, the 'P' at the beginning and part of padrao = '_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001.pdf'

The problem is that at the end of the padrao the number can be variable, the file can end with "02.pdf" , "03.pdf"

In the example I mentioned above, the folder 9883231 should contain both files.

Comment: ok but what isn't working? what is happening when you run this?

Comment: creates the folders and moves the files, but the folder has the wrong name if the pdf file does not contain the pattern _V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001.pdf, when for example _V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00002.pdf is wrong. @d6stringer

Comment: in short I need to replace in the name of the folder the following characters '_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S000**' + '.pdf'.

Where the ** can be 01, 02, 03, 04....

Comment: You need to come up with a better pattern. If your logic is to always take the first part o the file name until the first underscore and replace "P", then your code could do this with s simple str.split - if your logic is more complex you may have to resort to regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions can do the trick here:

```
import re
import os
import glob
import shutil


cwd = os.getcwd()
padrao = '_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S000'
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    dst = os.path.join(cwd, re.findall("P(.*)" + padrao + "\d{2}.pdf", file)[0])

    os.mkdir(dst)
    shutil.move(file, dst)
```

Notice that I remove the part of `padrao` that varies.
The regex matches all strings that begin ith a `P`, followed by the `padrao` string value, followed by 2 digits, followed by `.pdf`; and takes the first occurence (no check is made wether it found anything here ...)

Also, it is better practice to use `os.path.join()` to avoid issues when creating path strings (when whanging os notably)

Comment: thanks friend, it worked. I was just wondering, what is the function of [0]? @PlainRavioli

Comment: Glad it helped ! `[0]` takes the first match of the regex because `findall()` returns a list with all matches it found in the given string